# Prevent video output from Android Mobile to PC

Tags: android, video, television

Is it possible to disable my android device not to get detected in TV or PC if it is connected using USB ports ? I want to do it through programming using java or android.

Thanks,
Senthil.M

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write your own firmware. There is no support related to "detected in TV" anywhere in Android itself -- this capability is implemented on a device-by-device basis by different manufacturers. Hence, there is nothing in the SDK to control it, either.

Comment: Thanks for the reply dude. Actually I want my android application should not run in TV if suppose user has connected the mobile with TV using some AV cables. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: @Senthil: You will have to write your own firmware. There is no support related to "run in TV" anywhere in Android itself -- this capability is implemented on a device-by-device basis by different manufacturers. Hence, there is nothing in the SDK to control it, either.